# Is it Possible to add the same Post record in my custom Table when a Post is published as it goes to wp_post table?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a plugin for my client website. When I activate my plugin then a table is created in phpMyAdmin database by using `register_activation_hook()`. Now I want to add a new record in that custom table when `wp_post` is updated.
In other words, As I know that when a new post is published then this post data is inserted in `wp_post` table but is it possible to use any `action()` to insert that same post/page data in my custom table?

I have searched many actions that are called when a post is published or updated but these actions didn't work for me.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formatting text. Actually I am a new user here.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is in codex as per codex.wordpress.org. The link below will point you to all the function needed for your wordpress post. Go through it and access the post functions that has what you need.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29

**updates:**

You can hook up this function to insert into your custom table when publishing a post

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article "%s" has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );enter code here
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

now assuming your new table for insertion is nancy_table

you can insert as follows

```
// initialize database connections globals
global $wpdb;
$name = "nancy";
$post_new = "my post is here";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO nancy_table
        ( post_id, name, post_new )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        array(
        10, 
        $name, 
        $post_new
    ) 
) );
```

so finally you will have

```
    function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
        $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
        $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
        $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
        $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
        $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
        $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );


// your new post

global $wpdb;
$name = "nancy";
$post_new = "my post is here";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO nancy_table
        ( post_id, name, post_new )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        array(
        10, 
        $name, 
        $post_new
    ) 
) );



        $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article "%s" has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
        $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
        $headers[] = '';
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );enter code here
    }
    add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

You can read up this link to see how to work with wordpress database and tables via secured prepared statement.

db queries wordpress
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Each time a post is published, a new post is sent to your custom table. Please try other functions as well..

Comment: I have tried these post related actions but no one can help me in achieving my goal.

Comment: @MalikSaqibAwan Could you explain what exactly isn't working for you? Could you show us some code?

Comment: see updated section of my post. I have added some code.

Comment: Actually I am doing the stuff just like that what are you mentioned above but First error came Publish Failed. In actual wp_post record is added and no record is added in my custom table which is wp_page_settings.

Comment: see developers do not complain much, you keep on trying until you get it.  First create your table and copy the insert code only and save in a php files in wordpress directory and run it to see if you can successfully insert. then you can run the above code as a plugin or copy it into function.php. it must work

Comment: The table nancy_table must be created inside wordpress database

Comment: Yes, sure I am trying my best. My custom table is inserted in the WordPress database. Thanks!

Comment: am glad It helps. If it really help you solve your problem you can mark it as accepted to make it valuable for future SO users. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function insert_data_into_page_setting(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<script> alert('Row Inserted')</script>";
    $lastID = $wpdb->insert_id;
    $newRes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE ID=$lastID", ARRAY_A);
    foreach ($newRes as $values) {
        $wpdb->insert(
            'wp_page_settings',
            array('ID' => $lastID, 'post_title' => $values['post_title']),
            array('%d', '%s'));
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'insert_data_into_page_setting');
```

Comment: Here is the function which I am using to insert a new record in wp_page_setting table.